# How to change ListView over scroll?

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

How can I change a `ListView` to over scroll the header and footer?

I tried with setting attributes, but that has not worked.

```
android:overScrollHeader="@drawable/drawable_file"
android:overScrollFooter="@drawable/drawable_file"
```

Comment: I think we need to see more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved calling this after listView created

```
public static void brandGlowEffect(Context context) {       
        //glow
        int glowDrawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_glow", "drawable", "android");
        Drawable androidGlow = context.getResources().getDrawable(glowDrawableId);
        androidGlow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#3fade6"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        //edge
        int edgeDrawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_edge", "drawable", "android");
        Drawable androidEdge = context.getResources().getDrawable(edgeDrawableId);
        androidEdge.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#3fade6"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
  }
```

Thanks